# How to determine architecture to build GCC cross compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling, gnu, binutils

I'm trying to set up a build server on Linux which I will use to build C/C++ apps for Windows and Mac.
I know that GCC supports a body of different architectures but I can't figure out how to determine targets against which I need to build GCC cross compiler.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
I know that precompiled solutions already exist, but I just want to understand this in detail by making a deep dive.

Comment: Why don't you just use a few virtual machines to build natively on your target  platforms? So much easier than getting cross-compilation working properly (not worth the hassle IMHO).

Comment: @JesperJuhl That is true and I already utilize this approach. However I also want to understand C++ in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the target machine, run:

```
gcc -dumpmachine
```

Then use the result in the `--target` option when building your cross toolchain.